I want to connect google drive in web application and store image and retrieve image from drive without a service account
I want to connect google drive in web application and store image and retrieve image from drive without a service account.
In sample.net MVC project to implement functionality to connect with google drive and retrieve and upload or store images without create console service account.
you can take reference of draw.io or canva app. in that app already implement.
I try in sample project to implement functionality, but it give redirection issue. also it gives source not found error. and in last it give this error:

this is my controller:
   [GoogleScopedAuthorize(DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveReadonly)]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
   {
       // Get the user's Google Drive files from the service
       var files = await _googleDriveService.GetDriveFilesAsync();

       // Return the view with the list of files
       return View(files);
   }

this is my service
 public async Task<IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>> GetDriveFilesAsync()
 {
     // Check if the user is authenticated via cookie authentication
     var authResult = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();

     if (!authResult.Succeeded)
     {
         // User is not authenticated, throw an exception or handle as needed
         throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("User is not authenticated.");
     }

     // If authenticated, retrieve the credentials (access token)
     var credentials = authResult.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials))
     {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Access token is not available.");
     }

     // Proceed to use the credentials with the Google API
     var credential = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(credentials);
     var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
     {
         HttpClientInitializer = credential,
         ApplicationName = "anyname"
     });

     // Create a request to list the files
     var request = driveService.Files.List();
     request.PageSize = 10;
     request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

     // Execute the request
     var result = await request.ExecuteAsync();
     return result.Files;
 }

